# Electron application spontaneously crashes with no error logs and 0 exit code

Tags: node.js, electron

I am developing an Electron application using

- `electron@26.2.1`
- `sequelize@6.33.0`
- `@journeyapps/sqlcipher@5.3.1`
- `@electron-force/cli@6.4.2`
- `npm@9.5.1`
- Node v18.16.0
- Various other dependencies

I am running the application during development with `npm run start-electron` which maps to `electron-forge start`. The symptoms I'll describe below occur regularly during development on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04). I have also received reports that this is happening in early-access distributed builds of the application - these reports are currently unverified but concern Windows and Linux systems.

---

**What is happening?**

Regularly, and suddenly, the application main process quits without any warning or clear cause. The `node` process exits and I'm dropped back to the terminal.

- There is *no* log output in the terminal window.
- I have handlers registered for `uncaughtException` and `unhandledRejection`; they are not catching the event.
- A handler is registered for Electron's `before-quit` event. The handler implementation is responsible for cleaning up during a user-initiated shutdown. This handler is *not* invoked when the app disappears.
- The process exit code (`$?`) is always `0`.
- A single launch of the application can be stable for hours, then abruptly terminate. Other launches terminate almost immediately and are practically unusable.
- There is plenty of memory available (currently, 10 GiB physical unused on my machine). The app does not exhibit any runaway memory use that I've seen.
- I have noticed that quits *may* be occurring after a Sequelize query is run (these get logged to the console). This is hard to verify as it's not one specific query and disabling Sequelize is not viable, as the whole app is built on it.
- The `BrowserWindow` instance is kept as a global to avoid garbage collection.
- I am using `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1` and `ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING=1`.

---

I'm currently at a loss how to proceed with debugging. I rarely work with native applications, i.e. processes, as I usually focus on web apps and this Electron project has been something of a rare wildcard.

As the exit code is `0`, I was thinking that something is actually sending a quit event to the main process. But I'm unable to see or capture this using any of Electron's quit-related events. What steps am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried the options described [here](https://www.electronforge.io/advanced/debugging)?

Comment: @Arkellys I don't think that can provide any more info than I already have; `--inspect-electron`  allows connecting DevTools to the main process, but I already have the main process' logs in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem, and the problem is in  encrypted database (@journeyapps/sqlcipher).
https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/issues/1543

Comment: Thanks. I've got some way with investigating this, this issue description is outdated. I might try to update it. I now know it's actually crashing due to a SIGTRAP signal (137) each time it happens. I started inspecting the Electron crash dumps but haven't had much time and haven't been able to pinpoint exactly where or why it's going wrong yet.